# Why paths of length return 0 using Pytorch?

Tags: python-3.x, path, pytorch

This function return error which is same as below while the paths is correct. Am I misunderstanding how paths works? (This snippet is from [github-repo](https://github.com/carpedm20/ENAS-pytorch/blob/master/generate_gif.py))

```
paths = paths[::skip_frame]

ValueError: slice step cannot be zero
```

Here is the main function:

```
 def make_gif(paths, gif_path, max_frame=50, prefix=""):
      import imagei

paths.sort()
skip_frame = len(paths) // max_frame

paths = paths[::skip_frame]

images = [imageio.imread(path) for path in paths]
max_h, max_w, max_c = np.max(
        np.array([image.shape for image in images]), 0)
```

Here is how function called:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--model_name", type=str)
parser.add_argument("--max_frame", type=int, default=50)
parser.add_argument("--output", type=str, default="sampe.gif")
parser.add_argument("--title", type=str, default="")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    args = parser.parse_args()


    paths = glob(f"./logs/{args.model_name}/networks/*.png")

    make_gif(paths, args.output,
            max_frame=args.max_frame,
            prefix=f"{args.title}\n" if args.title else "")
```

Comment: What is the `len` of `paths`, and what is the value of `max_frame`? You're using integer division, so any answer `0 < n < 1` will be rounded down to 0.

Answer (score 0):

You get this error because your `skip_frame` is zero. Make sure it's value is at least one.